# Wordpress - can't move wp from localhost to live site

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have problem with moving wordpress from localhost to live site. I have successfully created and imported databes, update wp-config.php file, updated links in database - I can access wp-login. Did settings->general->check addresses->save. However, when I try to access address (it's not yet classic domain name, just internal address from webhosting provider), the page is just blank.

Does anyone know why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must probably still have invalid paths or urls in your updated database, or might be replacing serialized data with unserialized data. There's a really useful plugin for WP Db migration called [WP Migrate Db](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/). You should give it a try. If you do, don't forget to replace both urls and paths:

### URL Example:

`//localhost/sites/yoursite/`

with

`//yoursite.com`

### Path Example:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\yoursite`

with

`server/path/to/yoursite`

This path is usually detected by WP Migrate Db.